# hyperlink text not visible on webpage but link is there

Tags: html, href

I am not sure why my text for the link is not visible on the page but, when I take my mouse to the area where I was expecting a link text then I am able to click that 
blank area" and able to download correct file!

Here is the code structure:

```html
<html>
<head>
   some heading/styling link etc.
<body>
   some code related to creating dropdown and populating it (form used)
<?php
   if submit button is clicked then bunch of variables are populated and        
   user receives an email with result file. Ideally, I would like to be able 
   to display a result file link inside this php code.However, I don't know 
   if php allows to create a hyperlink. So, I was testing to create a link 
   outside php code. The php code does some python query.
   exec("/path/to/python script that does query $var1 $var2 $var3 2>&1", 
   $output)
?>
<a href="/<?php echo $output[8] ?>"Link to query result</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So, the text "Link to query result" is nowhere visible but the link exists. What is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor's opening tag misses '>'

Change

```
<a href="/<?php echo $output[8] ?>"Link to query result</a>
```

to

```
<a href="/<?php echo $output[8] ?>">Link to query result</a>
```

Comment: Anchor tag is missing. You have closed the PHP tag but not the anchor tag. Ahmad's solution will work for you.

Comment: The proposed solution didn't work.. However, I added some color to text and it worked fine.